# Restful service not returning right object

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a Java `Restful` web service , which when called by `postman` returns an object which is missing attributes. The `JSON` objects can be seen below.

The image below that shows the object just before it is returned in the rest function. As you can see, there are the days of the week with a value in them which are not showing up in postman.

The `backAbsence` entity can be view at the end of this post.

The `SAbsence` is a list of the `backAbsence` entity's.

> What I am wondering is why when i return the `SAbsenece` are the full models not received in postman and how do I resolve it?

```
[
    {
        "name": "King sean",
        "classidClass": 0,
        "studentidStudent": 1,
        "week": 14
    },
    {
        "name": "Sean king",
        "classidClass": 0,
        "studentidStudent": 2,
        "week": 14
    }
]
```

[image]

**Rest function Part:**

```
@GET
    @Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
    @Path("{id}/{option}")
    public List<BackAbsence> findbyClass(@PathParam("id")int id,
                                     @PathParam("option")int option) {

List<BackAbsence> SAbsence = new ArrayList<>();

// code here fills list. The Image above shows the object with valid attributes
 return SAbsence;
    }


}
```

**BackAbsnece Entity:**

```
public class BackAbsence {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private int classidClass;

    private int studentidStudent;

    private int monday = 0, tuesday = 0, wednesday = 0, thursday = 0, friday = 0;

    private int week;

     public BackAbsence() {
    }

     public BackAbsence(int idstudent, String name) {
    this.studentidStudent = idstudent;
    this.name = name;
     }

    public BackAbsence(int classidClass, int studentidStudent, int monday, int tuesday, int wednesday, int thursday, int friday,int week) {
        this.classidClass = classidClass;
        this.studentidStudent = studentidStudent;
       this.monday = monday;
       this.tuesday = tuesday;
       this.wednesday = wednesday;
       this.thursday = thursday;
        this.week = week;
    }

    public int isMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(int monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    public int isTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(int tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    public int isWednesday() {
        return wednesday;
    }

    public void setWednesday(int wednesday) {
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
    }

    public int isThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(int thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    public int isFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(int friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }


     public int getClassidClass() {
        return classidClass;
    }

    public void setClassidClass(int classidClass) {
        this.classidClass = classidClass;
    }

    public int getStudentidStudent() {
        return studentidStudent;
    }

    public void setStudentidStudent(int studentidStudent) {
        this.studentidStudent = studentidStudent;
    }



    public int getWeek() {
        return week;
    }

    public void setWeek(int week) {
        this.week = week;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hrm. you are using a "boolean" style getter getting for int fields.

```
 private int monday = 0, tuesday = 0, wednesday = 0, thursday = 0, friday = 0;
```

try changing this to getMonday, getTuesday etc or changing the integers to bools.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that whatever json mapper implementation you are using to do the conversion is only looking for java bean style getters and setters so is ignoring you int methods like isMonday(). Try changing them to getMonday() or find a different mapper implementation.